# Ошибка CS0019 в С#. Помогите разобратся

Tags: c#

Проблема следующего характера.
Вот код

```
double x;
double p;

//В button1
double x = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);
double p = Convert.ToDouble(textBox2.Text);
if (x > Math.Abs(p)) 
l = 2 * Math.Pow(Math.Pow(x, 2), 3) + 3 * Math.Pow(p, 2); 
else
    if (3 < x < Math.Abs(p))
    l = Math.Abs(Math.Pow(x, 2) - p);
    else
        if (x == Math.Abs(p))
        l = Math.Pow(Math.Pow(x, 2) - p, 2);
```

Эта строчка кода и выдаёт ошибку CS0019

```
if (3 < x < Math.Abs(p))
```

Я понимаю что этот оператор невозможно применить к типу bool и double но от задачи отходить нельзя.
Вот сама задача
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Lbhr.png

Comment: В C# вы не можете вот так вот делать несколько сравнений разом, их надо разделять на отдельные составляющие, которые будут возвращать один результат, а уже потом эти результаты "группировать". Условно `3 < x` - первое сравнение, `x < Math.Abs(p)` - второе, далее уже объединяем в одно с использованием "И" в условии, получаем `3 < x && x < Math.Abs(p)`, что логически будет так: если левая сторона `true`, то проверяем правую, если и она `true`, то на выходе будет `true`, если одна из сторон `false`, то и соответствующий выход.

Comment: Полный текст ошибки стоит приводить.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В C# нельзя сравнивать переменную с интервалом, так как в Python:

```
if (3 < x < Math.Abs(p))
```

Можно так:

```
if (x > 3 && x < Math.Abs(p))
```